# How do I uninstall RSS?

Tags: feeds, installation

I would like to uninstall RSS completely from Drupal 8, not only hide it from pages, but also disable the core logic behind it.

How do I achieve it?

Comment: I tried to look at any variable to disable it. I didn't find anything. It is not packaged in a specific module. So, I'm a bit clueless. I can hook to alter forms and menu links related to it but it is ugly as the logic always runs behind. I try to remove it completely to reduce my attack surface as for some of my websites I do not need any RSS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you encounter RSS, but I am only aware of it being on the front page. That feed is generated from a second display on the frontpage view:

[image: disable feed]

Other modules might define their own feeds in a similar fashion, but I have not found them yet.

There is no such thing as 'disable RSS', so you cannot disable it globally.

Comment: I will give it a try. But, if RSS is defined in a view why is there a global configuration page for it ?

Comment: Ah, yes, that is for the RSS display mode of content types. It is explained [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426139) and can be toggled per content-type on the _manage display_ tab. Only `article` has it by default. Just remove the checkbox in the _Custom display settings_.

Comment: But that display mode is (by default) only used for the view from the answer, so just removing the view should already solve your problem.